# iOS6 only - jammed when loading 2nd tab

Tags: objective-c, ios6, tabbar

My app has to load from the 2nd tab as per my code. Its working fine in all iOS except iOS6.

I am using `[appDelegateObj.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];`

When I run it in iOS6, mid-tab gets highlighted and services at both 1st and 2nd tab starts loading and finally gets jammed showing just the loading symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Suggest you to check example of [UITabBar of developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tabster/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011213) in your IOS6 deployment environment.

On top of that try setting selectedIndex of your UITabBarController, like this:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = indexOfTab;
```

Hope this helps...